# How to create a __repr__ of a namedtuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, namedtuple, repr

How do I create a special method `__repr__` where I can print, for example, `'6 of spades'` or `'Q of diamonds'`?

How do I access the data from the `namedtuple`, keeping in mind that I have a `list` of `namedtuple`s in `self._cards`?

```
import collections

cards = collections.namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit'])

class Deck:
    ranks = [str(n) for n in range (2,11)] + list('JQKA')
    suits = 'spades diamonds hearts clubs'.split()

    def __init__(self):
        self._cards = [cards(rank, suit) for suit in self.suits for rank in self.ranks]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._cards)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._cards[item]

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s of %s' % ()  # <-- don't know how to assign the string

b = ()
for i in b:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your issue right now is that you are trying to make the `__repr__` method inside of your `Deck` class. That method will only get called when you are trying to print `Deck` objects, however it seems like you are trying to print a message for a single Card instead. You could solve this by making a simple `Card` class with suit and rank as class variables, and storing a list of `Card` objects in your deck. This way you could write a `__repr__` method for the card class itself, and reference the card's suit and rank directly.

Answer (score 15):

It would be clearer if you renamed `cards` to `Card`, since that's the name you assigned to that class:

```
Card = collections.namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit'])
```

You can extend a `namedtuple` just like any other class, including to give it `__repr__` method. You can even reuse the class name, since a `class` statement is a type of assignment:

```
class Card(Card):
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.rank} of {self.suit}'
```

A more compact version would be

```
class Card(collections.namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit'])):
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.rank} of {self.suit}'
```

Answer (score 14):

You could use [`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) instead, which allows you to define methods normally:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Card(NamedTuple):
    rank: str
    suit: str
    def __repr__(self):
        return "{} of {}".format(self.rank, self.suit)
```